# xlsxwriter Python combine() Not Working

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I am trying to create a 'combined' chart using xlsxwriter but it seems like the combine() function no longer works.  If you simply use the demo code on their website (http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/example_chart_combined.html) you get an Attribute Error: 'ChartColumn' object has no attribute 'combine'.

Does anyone know what's going on with xlsxwriter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you are using an older version of the module prior to when the chart combine feature was added.

Check your version of xlsxwriter like this:

```
python -c 'import xlsxwriter; print(xlsxwriter.__version__)'
```

It need to be at least 0.6.8.

Comment: Never mind.... I upgraded a different Python environment.  Thanks for your help.  I should have noticed this earlier.

Answer (score 1):

I have raise same issue.
but now i upgrade my package and now version **0.9.9** works good